# Jumping to a second firmware on stm32f4

Tags: c, arm, stm32, cortex-m

I'm building a bootloader for an application running on a stm32.
The purpose of this is to be able to update the main application.

Since our software is pretty modular, my idea was to just configure a minimal version of it. All the initializations are the same, it jumps to a `main` function that contains all bootloader functionalities (checking if a new firmware is available on external flash, writing it to internal flash if that's the case) and in the end jumping to the actual application - which does the initialization all over again, but this time with additional peripherals, etc., eventually calling the real `main`.

The memory layout on the internal flash is like this

```
|0x08000000 boot loader
|----------------------
|0x08006000 application
```

bootloader main looks like this

```
extern void CallApplication(void);

int main(void) {
    printf("starting bootloader\n");

    printf("will jump to " TOSTRING(APP_START_ADDRESS) "\n");

    CallApplication();

    return 0;
}
```

where `CallApplication` is written in assembler

```
#define VTABLE_START_ADDRESS APP_START_ADDRESS
#define NVIC_VTABLE 0xE000ED08  // Vector Table Offset

    .globl CallApplication
    .thumb_func
CallApplication:
    // Set the application's vector table start address.
    movw    r0, #(VTABLE_START_ADDRESS & 0xffff)
    movt    r0, #(VTABLE_START_ADDRESS >> 16)
    movw    r1, #(NVIC_VTABLE & 0xffff)
    movt    r1, #(NVIC_VTABLE >> 16)
    str     r0, [r1]

    // Load the stack pointer from the application's vector table.
    ldr     sp, [r0]

    // Load the initial PC from the application's vector table and branch to
    // the application's entry point.
    ldr     r0, [r0, #4]
    bx      r0
```

This almost works - the 'real' application is called, does its initialization but eventually crashes for a yet unknown reason.
What's interesting though is that the fault ISR of the bootloader (`0x080022ae`) is being called, not that of the real application (> `0x08006000`) so something about setting the new vector table obviously failed.

```
2016-02-11 00:21:16,958 - INFO # init UART
2016-02-11 00:21:16,963 - INFO # Application:   boot_loader
2016-02-11 00:21:16,973 - INFO # -- init done, starting main --
2016-02-11 00:21:16,974 - INFO # starting bootloader
2016-02-11 00:21:16,976 - INFO # will jump to 0x8006000
2016-02-11 00:21:16,978 - INFO # init UART
2016-02-11 00:21:16,985 - INFO # Application:   hello_world
2016-02-11 00:21:17,797 - INFO # -- init done, starting main --
(hard fault led starts flashing)
```

*What am I missing here?*

The linker script for the main application defines

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08006000, LENGTH = 488K
  SRAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
}
```

whereas the bootloader does

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 24K
  SRAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
}
```

the rest is shared

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        _text = .;

        /*
         * The vector table must be placed to the top of the
         * memory map. To achieve this, it was assigned to a 
         * special section called ".isr_vector"
         */
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))

        /* followed by .text and .rodata: */
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)

        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    /* Just to make sure that the contents does not exceed the flash size */
    . = ORIGIN(FLASH) + LENGTH(FLASH);


    /*
     * .data and .bss are placed into SRAM:
     */
    .data : AT(ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text))
    {
        _data = .;
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM

    .bss :
    {
        /* _bss and _ebss will be required during initialization */
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        _ebss = .;
    } > SRAM

    .aux : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.auxdata) /* .auxdata section */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > SRAM

    /* Just to make sure that the contents does not exceed the SRAM size */
    . = ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM);
}
```

**Edit:** I rewrote the section where `VTOR` is set in C to make it clearer for me what's going on, but I still end up in the bootloader's DefaultISR

```
printf("starting bootloader\n");

printf("will jump to " TOSTRING(APP_START_ADDRESS) "\n");

printf("before: %x\n", SCB->VTOR);

SCB->VTOR += APP_START_ADDRESS;

printf("after: %x\n", SCB->VTOR);

asm volatile("mov r0, #0x6000");
asm volatile("ldr sp, [r0]");
asm volatile("ldr r0, [r0, #4]");
asm volatile("bx r0");
```

outputs

```
2016-02-11 23:49:31,833 - INFO # starting bootloader
2016-02-11 23:49:31,835 - INFO # will jump to 0x6000
2016-02-11 23:49:31,836 - INFO # before: 8000000
2016-02-11 23:49:31,837 - INFO # after: 8006000
2016-02-11 23:49:31,839 - INFO # init UART
2016-02-11 23:49:31,841 - INFO # …
```

Comment: That is hard to debuge remotely. where does the exception occur? Use a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: It crashes the moment I enable interrupts by calling `__set_BASEPRI(0)`

Comment: Man! Which exception?, check the SCS registers, status, address, etc. If you don't know what I'm talking about, read the manuals, namely the architecture reference manual, but also others. Cortex-M4 is not PIC16 or AVR.

Comment: Seems like I was mistaken, it doesn't crash, it just calls the default interrupt handler - the one of the bootloader still. So setting the new VTABLE didn't work.

Comment: Note: Use standard names. The vector register e.g. is `VTOR`. Sorry, I cannot help you further. Just one info: It is not the STM's fault! For me it works.

Comment: I didn't claim it's the STM's fault, I'm sure it does just what I'm telling it to do :p I still don't know what I'm missing about setting `SCB->VTOR`, I'm now adding my offset to it, but the old location keeps getting used to look up what ISR to jump to :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the CPU init function from the HAL was doing

```
  /* Configure the Vector Table location add offset address ------------------*/
#ifdef VECT_TAB_SRAM
  SCB->VTOR = SRAM_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal SRAM */
#else
  SCB->VTOR = FLASH_BASE | VECT_TAB_OFFSET; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal FLASH */
#endif
```

and by that overwriting my setting to `SCB->VTOR`.

It works when this is removed, no further magic required.

Answer (score 3):

In my case is a STM32L Cortex-M3, but I think it works in the same way.

In the bootloader, after disabling all sources of interrupt (not masking them), I do the following:

```
#define APP_LOCATION 0x08006000

typedef void (*pFunction)(void);
pFunction jump;
volatile uint32_t jumpAddress;
register uint32_t regMainStackPointer __ASM("msp");

void Jump( void ) {
    jumpAddress = *( volatile uint32_t* )( APP_LOCATION + 4 );
    jump = ( pFunction )jumpAddress;
    mainStackPointer = *( volatile uint32_t* )APP_LOCATION;
    jump();
}
```

And in the application itself, the first thing to do before enabling any interrupt is:

```
SCB->VTOR = 0x0x08006000;
```

The linkers here are equal.

I noticed something strange in your code:

```
SCB->VTOR += APP_START_ADDRESS;
```

If APP_START_ADDRESS contains the address (0x08006000) instead of the offset (0x6000), the resulting value in VTOR will be 0x08000000 + 0x08006000, perhaps the problem is here?

It might help if you show some code from the application.
Hope it helps.